# Qt :what is the best way to implement sleep function inside QThread?

Tags: c++, qt, sleep, qthread

i invoking QThread with creating object and using MoveToThread function like it suggest
inside the Object i have loop and i need to be able to set sleep for few seconds between iterations ( to update the main GUI ) searching the web got me to this link:
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/476-where-s-the-sleep%28%29-func
but this not working inside threads , what is the best way to do this ?

Comment: You might consider using a QTimer to send a signal to your thread periodically instead -- that way your thread wouldn't be blocked most of the time, and things like shutting down your application could happen faster (because your main thread wouldn't have to wait for your QThread to finish sleeping before the QThread::wait() returns)

Comment: Jeremy is right you should consider other possibilities, sleeping in threads is often a sign of a limitation of the architecture in use. Many solutions exists with and especially with Qt! Perhaps some code could help to find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at

```
void    msleep ( unsigned long msecs )
void    sleep ( unsigned long secs )
void    usleep ( unsigned long usecs )
```

methods of [QThread](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qthread.html)

These methods are all protected in qt4. So you need to derive from QThread to access them if you are using qt4. I am not sure if they were protected in qt3 or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got around the problem of the `QThread sleep` functions being protected:

```
// QThread has static sleep functions; but they're protected (duh).
// So we provide wrapper functions:
//
//    void MyLib::sleep (unsigned long secs)
//    void MyLib::msleep (unsigned long msecs)
//    void MyLib::usleep (unsigned long usecs)

#include <QThread>

namespace MyLib
  {
  class DerivedFromQThread : protected QThread
    {
  public:
    static void sleep (unsigned long secs)   { QThread::sleep (secs) ; }
    static void msleep (unsigned long msecs) { QThread::msleep (msecs) ; }
    static void usleep (unsigned long usecs) { QThread::usleep (usecs) ; }
    } ;
  void sleep (unsigned long secs)   { DerivedFromQThread::sleep (secs) ; }
  void msleep (unsigned long msecs) { DerivedFromQThread::msleep (msecs) ; }
  void usleep (unsigned long usecs) { DerivedFromQThread::usleep (usecs) ; }
  } // namespace MyLib
```